# Intersection of two parabolas with perpendicular axis

Tags: conic-sections

Let there be two parabolas:
$$y^2+2kx=k^2 \tag{1}$$
$$x^2+2ky=k^2 \tag{2}$$

What will be the point of intersection of these two curves? The [general form of intersection of such two curves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2295710/intersection-of-two-parabolas) would lead to solving a quartic equation([a lengthy solution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Solution)), which I want to avoid, since there is clear symmetry in the two parabolas, as visible after plotting them, and also evident from the [Wolfram's Solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+over+reals+y%5E2%2B2kx%3Dx%5E2%2B2ky%3Dk%5E2). So, I'm trying to find the solution by exploiting the symmetry (if possible), and not by going through the quartic equation.

Along the lines of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3567710/two-parabolas-perpendicular-axes-can-we-prove-the-intersection-points-are-conc), I added eqns (1) and (2):
$$y^2+x^2+2ky+2kx=2k^2$$
After completing the square,
$$(y+k)^2+(x+k)^2=(2k)^2\tag{3}$$

Let $k>0$, then the circle in (3) has centre at $O'=(-k,-k),$ and radius $2k$. For $k=6$, the parabolas and the circle look like this: [image: Figure]

Clearly, the first intersection point $P(x,y)$ has $x>0,y>0$. Drawing a radius from centre of circle $O'$ to point $P(x,y)$, $O'P=2k$.
Let origin be $O(0,0)$. Then $O'O= \sqrt2 k$.
As $O'P=O'O+OP,$ $ OP=2k-\sqrt 2 k= \sqrt2 k(\sqrt2-1)$.
Also, $OP=\sqrt{x^2+y^2},$
so $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}= \sqrt2 k(\sqrt 2 -1)$

Now I only need to put $x=y$ to obtain $x=y=k(\sqrt 2-1)$, which is indeed one of the solution given by Wolfram Alpha (for $k>0$). However, I can't think of how to state $x=y$; I assumed this after seeing the solution by WA. But, if we let $x=y$ in (1) and (2), then it reduces to solving a quadratic and all solutions can be obtained as $x=y=\pm \sqrt2 |k|-k$.

By (3), the circle has centre at $(-k,-k)$, which means the circle remains the same even if we interchange the X and Y axis. And since the intersection points lie on the circle, so $x=y$ for intersection point(s) $P(x,y)$. Is this reasoning correct? It feels more like an assumption, but it gives the answer, so it is true, but how can it be proven? Or is there any alternative for finding solution?

Comment: Substract the equations...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have no idea how I missed this. Subtracting the eqns, it gives $y=x$ (which is true), and $y+x+2k=0$. How to know that the second equality doesn't hold?

Comment: this is $y+x-2k=0$ report in the original equations and eventually discard it (delta<0)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since one curve is the reflection of the other across the line $y = x$,
there are two possible kinds of intersections:

- Points on the line $y = x$.
- Pairs of points not on the line $y = x$, such that the pair is symmetric across the line $y = x$.

To find points of the first kind, replace $y$ be $x$ in one of the equations.
(Choose either equation; the result is the same.)
Now you just have to solve a quadratic equation in $x$.

The rest of the solution is to show that there are no other solutions.
Graphically, it's obvious, but I don't propose that as a proof.

From $x^2+2ky=y^2+2kx$ we can derive

$$ (x + y)(x - y) = 2k(x - y), $$

so either $x - y = 0$ (the first kind of solution) or $x + y = 2k$.
Substituting $2k - x$ for $y$ in Equation $(1)$, we find that $x = k = 0$,
hence also $y = 0$, so this is actually not a solution of the second kind but just the first kind of solution for the special case where $k = 0$.

---

In fact, the solution of $x^2+2kx=k^2$ along with the assertion $y = x$ finds both of the actual solutions.

Comment: The intersection points of first kind seems more obvious to me than those of second kind. The first kind can be interpreted as solution of $f(x)= f^{-1}(x)$ ( the eqns here aren't functions, it's just an analogy), and solution of $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ lie on   $y=x$. But how does intersection points of second kind exist?

Comment: The second kind does **not** exist in this problem. But consider the intersection points of the two curves $x^2+2y^2=1$ and $y^2+2x^2=1$. Then you have both kinds of solution. The idea is that if there is any intersection that is **not** on the line $y=x$, then you can reflect both curves across $y=x$ and the intersection also is reflected across $y=x$. Therefore such intersections can only occur in pairs.

Comment: Thanks. I'm closing the question now.